# Insert milliseconds from MS-Sql server in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp

I am interested in knowing if there is a way I can insert the millis from the MS-Sql server in a table.

I know this is possible with MySql, but I couldn't find a way to do this with MS-Sql.

I can of course read the millis from my computer and add them in my query so that I write them in my table, but I would like the MS Sql server directly to fill up a column "TimeStamp" with its milliseconds time.
Any idea here?
Thanks!

Comment: What is a "millis"?

Comment: @Larnu * milliseconds ;-)

Comment: A `datetime` is accurate to 1/300th of a second (3.3333~ milliseconds), and a `datetime2` can be up to 100nanoseconds; so yes, you can store milliseconds very easily.

Comment: Also, `timestamp` is not a date and time value in SQL Server. `timestamp` is a synonym of `rowversion`, which is a `binary` value, not a date and time value.

Comment: @Larnu but what do I have to use to insert `datetime` milliseconds, being this date the date from the server? Ideally, i should not give in my query any value to `datetime` or to `datetime2`

Comment: Use an `INSERT`; like you would any any other data type... An `INSERT` statement doesn't change because you're using a date and time value... I feel like we're not being told your *real* question here and this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEPART( MILLISECOND , GETDATE())
```

Comment: how would you do with an `INSERT`? does `GETDATE()` return `milliseconds`?

Comment: yes it does , and DATEPART returns milisecond and you can save it in an int column anywhere

Comment: `GETDATE` is a `datetime` @p.j.smith.